# elasticsearch bulk queue size

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I'm monitoring the elasticsearch cluster while bulk importing data.

So when I run curl localhost:9200/_cat/thread_pool?v

it shows:

```
host            ip           bulk.active bulk.queue bulk.rejected index.active index.queue index.rejected search.active search.queue search.rejected 
xye@OptiPlex  127.0.0.1            8          6             0            0           0              0             0            0               0
```

I'm current running 5 scripts concurrently to import the data and the bulk size is 500 and I also increased the bulk queue size too 300.

So I'm wondering what bulk.queue 6 means. Is it just 6 documents in one bulk operation or it is actually 6 bulk requests which is 6 * 500 = 3000 documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bulk.queue` represents the number of bulk requests in the queue and not the number of documents. `index.queue` would represent the number of documents to be indexed present in the `index queue`.

Comment: So if I set the bulk queue very large, is it possible to avoid EsRejectedExecutionException?

Comment: is bulk.rejected also represent # documents  or # bulk operations?

Comment: @milodky I know this is very late but setting the bulk queue to a very large value has its own problems. You may run into memory issues trying to keep so many bulk requests in memory at the same time.

Comment: @ShaiM. No, bulk.rejected represents the number of bulk request failures.